# How to make gray spaces disappear?

Tags: modeling

I have a question
Blender "eats" my constructions with gray spaces.
I would like to know how to move away those gray spaces so that I can work with more space.
Thank you so much to anyone who answers me!

[image: gray spaces.]

Comment: Fantastic! But in the latest version of blender is the same site the commands?

Comment: Yes, why don't you try it??

Comment: I reset the blender settings because I could not find it. Now I've been able to find, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Great! Welcome to Blender.se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: 3d view clip end]

Press <kbd>N</kbd>  on your keyboard to open the *Properties Panel*, then go to the area marked with red.

Then increase the *Clip End* to fit your work